# UICollectionView low frame rate

Tags: ios, performance, frame-rate, collectionview

I have a collection view that displays 3 images, two labels, and 1 attributed string(strings are of different colors and font sizes and values are not unique for every cell). One of the images is coming from the web and I used AFnetworking to do the downloading and caching. The collection view displays 15 cells simultaneously.

When I scroll I can only achieve 25 frames/sec.

Below are the things I did:
-Processing of data were done ahead and cached to objects
-Image and views are opaque
-Cells and views are reused

I have done all the optimizations I know but I can't achieve at least 55 frames/sec.

If you could share other techniques to speed up the re-use of cells.

I was even thinking of pre-rendering the subviews off screen and cache it somewhere but I am not sure how it is done.

When I run the app on the iPhone it is fast since it only shows at least four cells at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is fire up instruments and find out if you're ***CPU-bound*** (computation or regular I/O is a bottleneck) or ***GPU-bound*** (the graphics card is struggling). . depending on which of these is the issue the solution varies.

Here's a [video tutorial](http://vimeo.com/channels/melbournecocoaheads/59729571) that shows how to do this (among other things) . . This one is from Sean Woodhouse @ Itty Bitty Apps (they make the fine [Reveal](http://revealapp.com/) tool).

NB: In the context of performance tuning we usually talk about being I/O bound or CPU bound as separate concerns, however I've grouped them together here meaning "due to either slow computation or I/O data is not getting to the graphics card fast enough". . if this is indeed the problem, then the next step is to find out whether it is indeed related to waiting on I/O or the CPU is maxed-out.

Instruments can be really confusing at first, but the above videos helped me to harness its power.

And here's another great tutorial from [Anthony Egerton](http://sydneycocoaheads.com/2012/09/26/anthony-egertons-introduction-to-instruments-at-september-sydney-cocoaheads/).

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of the image that you use?

One of the optimization technique which would work is that
Resize the image so that it matches the size of the view you are displaying.

Comment: That didn't work. All tasks such as what you've mentioned are done on another thread before being displayed.